# not valid .gitlab-ci.yml. I got the message "No stages / jobs for this pipeline"

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to publish a static page public/index.html via the gitlab pages CI feature. My .gitlab-ci.yml file is as follows

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

While the validation of the file is successful, when i try to validate it using the "Simulate a pipeline created for the default branch " option i get the message "No stages / jobs for this pipeline." I do not know what is wrong with my CI file... It seems right to me.

Any help is more than welcome

Comment: What is your default branch name? GitLab's new project default branch name is `main`. Your .gitlab-ci.yml `only` in `master`,  if the default branch name is `main` is not match.

Comment: you are so right!!! Thank you so much....it took me so much time to focus on the most simple fact that the master is named main....Feel free to add this as a response in order to vote it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your default branch name?

GitLab's new project default branch name is "main". Your .gitlab-ci.yml only in "master", if the default branch name is "main" is not match.